# In Spark, is it possible to create a separate background task for each executor?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

In my N node cluster, I will have one executor per node, and as many tasks per executor as the number of cores on a node. However, for some reason, I also want to create a special background task for each executor. That special task could for example be used for profiling a node or for combining files created by the other tasks on a node. So, my question is, is it possible to create such special background tasks for executors in Spark?

Comment: Since each executor is a separate JVM process, you can create a transient object which is initialized lazily. It in turn can start a background thread to do what you want. Although that is possible, It's definitely not something I personally would consider idiomatic for Spark. You need to view executors as disposable resources which can be terminated and allocated based on the clusters needs.

Comment: Since several tasks would be running on the same executor, from which task, you would create that thread and how? Would you have to use some kind of a mutex or something?

Comment: It doesn't matter, once it is a `lazy val`, it's synchronized and can only be invoked by one thread.